# angular user-idle-service premature issue

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ide

Using user-idle-service (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-user-idle) for angular.
Very rare users are getting kicked out prematurely when they are active.

Below is the code implementation.

```
constructor(   
    private userIdle: UserIdleService    
  ) {
    
  }
```

```
ngOnInit() {  

 this.userIdle.setConfigValues({
      idle: config.idle,
      timeout: config.timeout,
      ping: 5
    });

    // Start watching for user inactivity.
    this.userIdle.startWatching();

    // Start watching when user idle is starting.
    const uITimerStartSubscription = this.userIdle.onTimerStart().subscribe((count) => {
      if (this.router.url.indexOf('system/status') > -1) {
        this.userIdle.resetTimer();
        return;
      }
      console.log(count);
      this.dialogTimeOut = count > 0 ? true : false;      
    });

    this.subscription.add(uITimerStartSubscription);

    // Start watch when time is up.
    const uITimeroutSubscription = this.userIdle.onTimeout().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {     

      this.authService.clearSession();
    });
    this.subscription.add(uITimeroutSubscription);
}
```

Do not time out when the users are actively using the web app